# Put data on ServersideProps

Tags: node.js, typescript, next.js

Is it possible to get data from server side's config file on client by getServersideProps() in Next.js? How to put data in props? Or how to get it on client in other way?
I have tried `publicRuntimeConfig` in next.config.js, but it is undefined and I don't know why...

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell exactly what's going on but I have one idea from experience: You need to make sure you're calling `nextJSApp.prepare()` *before* any modules using `next/config` are included.

As an example,

```
// SomeComponent.tsx
import { getConfig } from 'next/config'

const config = getConfig()

export interface X { ... }
```

```
// server.ts
import { X } from './SomeComponent'

app.prepare().then(...)
```

This fails because module are loaded first and the config hasn't been initialized until `app.prepare` has been completed.

The solution for this is to either use TypeScript's `import(...)` syntax if you just need a type or use node's `require` for dynamic resolution during runtime.